# notary change transactions from validating to non-validating notaries

Tags: corda

while doing a notary change transaction from validating notaries to a new set of non validating notaries, how does the new set of non-validating notaries learn about the previous transactions?.

Do they get only the hashes of previous transactions or the entire transaction dependency graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new notary does not learn about the past transactions at all.

Instead, we have the following process:

- A transaction with hash `2772BE` and notary `NotaryA` is committed to the ledger
- Someone wants to transfer the first output state of this transaction (denoted `<2772BE, 0>`) to `NotaryB`
- They form a notary change transaction with a single input, `<2772BE, 0>`. Let's say the hash of this notary change transaction is `35D0A5`
- `NotaryA` signs this transaction, marking its input `<2772BE, 0>` as spent
- However, this transaction also creates one output state, `<35D0A5, 0>`, pointing to `NotaryB`
- `<2772BE, 0>`, which pointed to `NotaryA`, is now spent. But `<35D0A5, 0>`, which points to `NotaryB`, is unspent

In this way, we have transferred the state to a new notary in a way that prevents double-spends.