# Syntax for Notary change Transaction in Corda

Tags: corda

How will a notary change transaction look like in Corda ? I understood what actually happens from here [notary change transactions from validating to non-validating notaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50136031/notary-change-transactions-from-validating-to-non-validating-notaries)

But how will be the TransactionBuilder syntax for Notary change ?

Will the TransactionBuilder have two notaries added along with same input and output state ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notary-change transactions are not constructed using the standard `TransactionBuilder`. They have their own dedicated transaction builder called `NotaryChangeTransactionBuilder`.

`NotaryChangeTransactionBuilder` has the following constructor:

```
class NotaryChangeTransactionBuilder(
        val inputs: List<StateRef>,
        val notary: Party,
        val newNotary: Party)
```