# Notaries in Corda

Tags: corda

I know about how notaries prevent double-spending but I have a confusion regarding that.
Do all notaries use a single spent pairs map? Or the referred notary in a transaction will send the transaction details to other notaries to note it in their own map? If other notaries will not be informed about a transaction then a node can double-spend the same input state by referring another notary.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the notaries use a single spent map.
That means when a transaction referring to a new notary is trying to mark a state as "spent", it would first visit the original notary.

In addition, you can also create a notary-change-transaction by using NotaryChangeTransactionBuilder.
Check the answer of this question that gives a detailed steps on how a notary changed is performed.
[notary change transactions from validating to non-validating notaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50136031/notary-change-transactions-from-validating-to-non-validating-notaries)

Answer (score 0):

Your observations are correct, and that's why when you create an instance of `TransactionBuilder` you must specify the notary; all input states to that transaction builder must have been created using that same notary.
Otherwise, your notary won't be able to say whether those input stats were consumed or not.

So in short, all input states of your transaction must have the same notary; which matches the notary that you specified in your `TransactionBuilder`.

The above applies to reference states as well.